# OAuth Class not found

Tags: php, oauth

I have a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 installation with a basic web server setup including pecl and OAuth; However, when I run a simple index file (as shown below) I am getting a fatal error:

*PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found in /var/www/index.php on line 2*

Here is my file:

```
<?php
$oAuth = new \OAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY);
```

Obviously the consumer/private keys are my actual keys.

Now I have checked phpinfo() and OAuth is definitely in there. I have it set in my php.ini. I have restarted Apache.

When I run `pecl list`

> ## Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net
>
> Package   Version State 
>   oauth     1.2.3
>   stable pecl_http 1.7.6   stable

```
 extension_loaded('oauth') // returns true
```

there's no oAuth in `php -m` either

Any ideas why I am still getting class not found? I hope it's not something dumb I am missing :)

Cheers guys.